# Making MYSQL users accessible via internet

Tags: mysql, mariadb, remote-access

My sql user is "mail" with host "localhost". If I change the host to "%", it is still not accessible via internet. The only difference is that I can no longer login on locally. Did I forget something? 
Error message:

```
MySQLNo connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

The firewall has already been deactivated as a test, but without success. Mariadb is configured by default. The operating system is debian. Restart of the service/server has also been done. If you need more detailed information, let me know. thanks for your attention

Comment: Before you do this make *sure* your machine is locked down, that your `root` password is sufficiently robust, and that other services which could be used to attack your machine are properly secured or blocked.

Comment: It's not a great idea to open a MySQL database to the Internet. Though it can be done, the database is usually used from an intranet (for security reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to adjust this into your config:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

As for "localhost", this means local socket. Try connecting to the server on 127.0.0.1 and it should let you in.

Comment: thank you very much. it helps, but i got another error when i tried to connect with remote:  Failed to connect to MySQLAccess denied for user 'vmail'@'%' to database 'domains'
The user have all rights for this database in mysql....

Comment: What does `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'vmail'@'%' say? Have you tried resetting the password? Are you using any kind of external authentication, e.g. PAM?

Comment: this command gives: GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'vmail'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'HIDDEN'
i don't think it is necessary to reset the password, because i can log in via the console. No i havent external authentication or nothing extra set

Comment: Does it work when you try to log in from the console using: `mysql -h your.external.ip.address -uvmail -p` ? If you are connecting to the external IP address on the host that exercises the exact same code path as logging in from a different machine. Do you have the password saved in ~/.my.cnf on the local machine?

Comment: thats strange... i can connect with this command to my database local and remote. is it maybe a problem of my php code?... when i use your last command, i need to type "use vmail". is this maybe my problem?

Comment: If you can connect using the CLI, that confirms that whatever the remaining problem is, it's not on the DB side. I don't know why your code is failing to connect.